Error: Unable to find tRPC Context. Did you forget to wrap your App inside `withTRPC` HoC?
Question:
I'm encountering an issue with my Next.js application where I'm trying to use tRPC for API handling. I'm getting the following error:
Error: Unable to find tRPC Context. Did you forget to wrap your App inside `withTRPC` HoC?

Error Details:
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Unable to find tRPC Context. Did you forget to wrap your App inside `withTRPC` HoC?

Source
src\app\auth-callback\page.tsx (11:69) @ useQuery

   9 |     const origin = searchParams.get('orogin')
  10 |
> 11 |     const {data, isLoading, isError, isSuccess} = trpc.authCallback.useQuery();
     |                                                                     ^
  12 |     if (isSuccess) {
  13 |       // user is synced to db
  14 |       router.push(origin ? `/${origin}` : '/dashboard')

Relevant Code:
src/app/layout.tsx:
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";
import Navbar from "@/components/Navbar";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en" className="light">
      <body className={cn(
        'min-h-screen font-sans antialiased grainy',
        inter.className
      )}>
        <Navbar />
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}


src/app/_trpc/config.ts:
import { AppRouter } from '@/trpc';
import { withTRPC } from '@trpc/next';

function getBaseUrl() {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    return '';
  }
  if (process.env.VERCEL_URL) {
    return `https://${process.env.VERCEL_URL}`;
  }
  return `http://localhost:${process.env.PORT ?? 3000}`;
}

export const withTRPCConfig = withTRPC<AppRouter>({
  config({ ctx }) {
    return {
      url: `${getBaseUrl()}/api/trpc`,
    };
  },
  ssr: false,
});

src/app/api/trpc/[trpc]/route.ts:
import { fetchRequestHandler } from '@trpc/server/adapters/fetch';
import { appRouter } from '@/trpc';

const handler = (req: Request) =>
  fetchRequestHandler({
    endpoint: '/api/trpc',
    req,
    router: appRouter,
    createContext: () => ({}),
  });

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };

src/app/auth-callback/page.tsx:
"use client"
import { useRouter, useSearchParams } from "next/navigation"
import { trpc } from "../_trpc/client"

const Page = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const searchParams = useSearchParams()
  const origin = searchParams.get('orogin')

  const { data, isLoading, isError, isSuccess } = trpc.authCallback.useQuery();
  if (isSuccess) {
    router.push(origin ? `/${origin}` : '/dashboard')
  }
}

export default Page

src/trpc/index.ts:
import { getKindeServerSession } from '@kinde-oss/kinde-auth-nextjs/server';
import { publicProcedure, router } from './trpc';
import { TRPCError } from '@trpc/server';

export const appRouter = router({
  authCallback: publicProcedure.query(async () => {
    const { getUser } = getKindeServerSession();
    const user = await getUser();

    if (!user?.id || !user?.email)
      throw new TRPCError({ code: 'UNAUTHORIZED' });

    return { success: true };
  }),
});

export type AppRouter = typeof appRouter;

src/trpc/trpc.ts:
import { initTRPC } from '@trpc/server';

const t = initTRPC.create();

export const router = t.router;
export const publicProcedure = t.procedure;

Additional Details:

Next.js version: "14.2.3"
React version: "^18"
tRPC version: 11.0.0-rc.374
@tanstack/react-query version: "^5.37.1"

What I've Tried:

Checked the API route configuration and endpoint URLs.
Verified the TRPC setup and procedure definitions.

Question:
Since I am using tRPC for the first time I don't why am I encountering the Unable to find tRPC Context error, Is there anything I've missed or misconfigured in the setup?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!
